# Start new row when pushing array to create CSV

Tags: javascript

My code is basically like this:

```
function allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr) {
    if(curstr.length == length) return [ curstr ];
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       ret.push.apply(ret, allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr + input[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}

var input = [ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' ];
var codee = [];
codee.push(allPossibleCombinations(input, 4, ''));
var csvRows = [];

for(var i=0, l=codee.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(codee[i].join(','));
}

var csvString = csvRows.join('\r\n');
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

What this outputs is a file with "AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD" being the headers for the first 4 columns. I'd like these values to all just be in the first column, but each value in its own row.

What can I change here to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: `codee[i]` is a string, you should be getting a TypeError there when calling `.join(',')`. Would be better if you could turn this into a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @chazsolo I'm not getting a type error.

Comment: Are you running the code you posted? Certainly `codee[i].join` is not a function. If you are running code that _isn't in the question_ you should update the question body.

Comment: If I console.log the array I'm actually using, it looks like this in the console:

0: (279841) ["AAAA", "AAAB", "AAAC", "AAAD", "AAAE", "AAAF",

Comment: So it's an array within an array? That is different than what you've posted, which is a single array with strings as values.

Comment: No...I don't believe so. I'm just pushing a short string one at a time into an empty array, so it shouldn't be an array in an array.

Comment: Just updated @chazsolo with the code that generates the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allPossibleCombinations` method returns array of array. The `codee` variable is a 2 dimensional array with only 1 outer element and all the different combinations are it's child. So, in this case, you just have to do a simple assignment operation (rather than using loop): `csvRows = codee[0]`. This will serve your purpose.

```js
function allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr) {
    if(curstr.length == length) return [ curstr ];
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       ret.push.apply(ret, allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr + input[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}

var input = [ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' ];
var codee = [];

codee.push(allPossibleCombinations(input, 4, ''));

var csvRows = codee[0];

/*
for(var i=0, l=codee.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(codee[i].join(','));
}
*/
var csvString = csvRows.join('\r\n');
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: This gives the same result.

Comment: you want something like this only, right?

`AAA` - A1
`BBB` - A2
`CCC`- A3
`DDD`- A4

Comment: That's what I want, but that's not what happening. Maybe my array isn't actually like what I have in my pseudocode.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I use to generate the array in the first place.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your updated question. Please have a look and let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: For some reason, this isn't downloading anything automatically now.

Comment: Not sure about exact issue but this might be due to your browser restricting multiple downloads from a particular url. Look for a block symbol/icon in your browser's address bar. You would have to allow that. Nevertheless, I have tested this code on codepen, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you have a working codepen because I can't get it working there or on jsfiddle?

Comment: You can just click on "Run Code Snippet" button just below my answer and your excel document will be downloaded.

Comment: Finally got it to download on Safari, but it's only giving around 10-12 rows with all the codes mashed together

Comment: Not sure what's the issue with your system. I have created a codepen (https://codepen.io/shubhaw/pen/jOPKVro). Just add `a.click()` at the end and check the downloaded file.

Comment: I did and got it to download from codepen, but I'm still getting 30 something rows instead of hundreds of thousands. All the possible code options are in there, but they aren't separated by line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209808/discussion-between-shubhaw-kumar-and-jonmrich).